# Condition for the (Stieltjes-) integral functional is aligned with the integrald

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

The following is from Luenberger "Optimization by Vector Space Methods" (p.117, example 2).

Let $x\in X=C[a,b]$ and let $\Gamma=\{t\in[a,b]\mid |x(t)|=\|x\|\}$, where $\|x\|=\sup_t |x(t)|$.

Say that a vector $x^* \in X^* $ is aligned with $x \in X$ if the evaluation of $x^*$ at $x$ is equal to the product of the norms of the two.

The claim is that a bounded linear functional $x^*(x)=\int_a^b x(t) dv(t)$ is aligned with $x$ if and only if $v$ varies only on $\Gamma$ and $v$ is nondecreasing at $t$ if $x>0$ and nonincreasing if $x<0$.

I'm not sure how to prove this claim. Can I explicitly compute the norm of $x^*$?

Comment: Hint: $dv(t)=h(t)d\mu (t)$ for some positive measure $\mu$and some $h$  with $|h(t)|=1$. You have to find out when equality holds in $|\int_a^{b} x(t)h(t)d\mu (t)|\leq \|x\| \mu ([a,b])$.  You should show some effort now before you can expect more details.

Comment: @geetha290krm The decomposition is $h=\mathrm{sgn}v$ to deal with the case $v<0$, right? Even assuming $v>0$, I'm not sure the inequality you mention and how to proceed. I know that $\left< x, x^* \right> \le \lVert x \rVert \lVert x^* \rVert$, so I need to find out when equality holds in $\int_a^b x dv \le \lVert x \rVert \sup_{||x||\le 1} |\int_a^b x dv|/||x||$. If $v$ is differentiable, I can apply the equality condition of the Holder for $\int_a^b x(t) v'(t) dt$, but clearly this is not the case.

Comment: I see now the inequality you showed because $x h\equiv 1$ achieves the sup in the definition of the norm, but still not sure how to show the equality condition. I can see that if $x h \equiv 1$, then the equality holds, but I need a condition on $v$ (or $\mu$) such that the equality holds for all $x$, right?

Comment: Is the following idea? If we assume that $v>0$, then  $\int_a^b x dv=\int_\Gamma x dv + \int_{\Gamma^c}dv=||x|| v(\Gamma) + \int_{\Gamma^c}dv$, so $\int_{\Gamma^c}dv=0$, i.e., $dv=0$ on $\Gamma^c$. To have $v(\Gamma)=v([a,b])=v(b)-v(a)$, we need $v$ to be nondecreasing. We can extend to the case $x$ is not always positive by @geetha290krm's hint.

Comment: Aren't you also assuimg that $x(t)>0$?

Comment: Ah yes I can modify the argument by splitting $\Gamma$ to $\Gamma\cap\{x>0\}$ and $\Gamma\cap\{x<0\}$, right? But I think the above argument shows sufficiency not necessity. Can I show necessity from a similar argument?